# how do you freeze / fake time with Jasmine BDD

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine

I have a line like this in my code

```
new Date().getFullYear();
```

and I need it to always return the same year.

Is there any way to do this with Jasmine ?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just stub the Date instance method like any other class?

Comment: Same way as the examples in their docs, but with date instead--can't try it now but I'd think it'd work the same way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JavaScript you can simply overwrite the function in your test setup:

```
Date.prototype.getFullYear = function(){return 2012}
```

You could also use a [jasmine spy](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies):

```
spyOn(Date, 'getFullYear').andReturn(2012)
```

Another way is to insert the date into your function you wanna test. Which is btw. the best way to write testable code. Dont create new instances in your functions, cause you always start to test not only your code but also this instances.

Comment: Should probably be `spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getFullYear').andReturn(2012)`.

Comment: This worked for me:
`spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getFullYear').and.returnValue(2012)`

Comment: If you overwrite the function, be sure to restore it after the unit test so that the overloaded function doesn't leak to other tests, or perhaps even the application.
1. `const originalGetFullYear = Date.prototype.getFullYear`, 2. Do the test, 3. `Date.prototype.getFullYear = originalGetFullYear`

Answer (score 2):

Sinon.js fake timers.

http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock

I built a drum machine in Node.js using this in my specs to check the timing code. but I also worked with it on another project where the only way I could get it to be the year I wanted was by using one specific year, I think 1969 for some reason. I'm guessing that's the start of the Unix era.

anyway, that was almost a year ago, so they've probably fixed it by now.

Comment: Unix Time started on 1/1/1970. It was a Thursday. :)

Comment: where is the drum machine?